# Get specific Key Value in side a loop

Tags: c#

I have a public method which return's collection of keys and values of an item and i would like to output specific key values. following is the method i am using

```
public List<string> GetAll(string itemSystemname) 
{
  return itemValues[itemSystemname].Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
}
```

All the values are printed out using foreach like this

```
foreach (var item in i.GetAll("FrontPageNewsLarge"))
{
  @item  
}

OutPut:
Name,
address,
phone,
city,
Name,
address,
phone,
city
```

and my desire way to Out the value's is like this

```
foreach (var item in i.GetAll("FrontPageNewsLarge"))
{
  @item.getvalue("name") // OR item["ID"]  
}



OutPut:
Name,
Name
```

ItemValues are initiated like this.

```
public class ItemRepository 
{
    public Dictionary<string, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> itemValues = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

    public ItemRepository(ItemCollection items) 
    {
        // populate fields

        foreach (var itemnames in items)
        {
            if (!itemValues.ContainsKey(itemnames.SystemName))
                itemValues.Add(itemnames.SystemName, new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>());

            var nameList = itemnames.Names.ToList();
            var valueList = itemnames.Values.ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < itemnames.Names.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (valueList[i] != null && nameList[i] != null) 
                { 
                    var name = nameList[i].ToString();
                    var value = valueList[i].ToString();
                    itemValues[itemnames.SystemName].Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name, value));
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    public string Get(string itemSystemname, string fieldnames) 
    {
        if (itemValues != null && itemValues[itemSystemname] != null && itemValues[itemSystemname].Any(f => f.Key == fieldnames))
        {
            return itemValues[itemSystemname].FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == fieldnames).Value;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public List<string> GetAll(string itemSystemname) 
    {
        return itemValues[itemSystemname].Where(item => item.Key == "Id").ToList();
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this functionality. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you show what `itemValues` is?

Comment: And what is the difference between `@item` and `item`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I think it may be Razor syntax with the @ symbol

Comment: Your returning a list or strings not a dictionary or list of keyvaluepairs

Comment: @GiladGreen I have updated my question You can see the ItemValues

Comment: @GiladGreen I have update my question again and added the actual code

Comment: @UmarKhan - See what I edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Update: itemValues is from type: `Dictionary<string, HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>`

A HashSet doesn't implement an `[]` operator so you can't do it the way you wanted. What you should do is:

```
itemValues["FrontPageNewsLarge"].Where(item => item.Key == "ID")

//For when you get the field from a parameter and what to output only the "value"
itemValues[itemSystemname].Where(f => f.Key == fieldNames).Select(f=> f.Value)
```

Or change `itemValues` to something like bellow

---

Assuming that `itemValues` is something like `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> itemValues = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, someObject>>`

Then just:

```
public Dictionary<string, someObject> GetAll(string itemSystemname) 
{
    return itemValues[itemSystemname];
}

foreach (var item in i.GetAll("FrontPageNewsLarge"))
{
    item["ID"];
}
```

But for that why use a function? just write:

```
foreach(var item in itemValues["FrontPageNewsLarge"])
{
    var doSomethingWith = item["ID"];
}
```

*(just make sure that "FrontPageNewsLarge" and "ID" actually exist in the dictionary)*

What you can also do, if you need all the ids:

```
itemValues["FrontPageNewsLarge"].Select(item => item["ID"]);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it didn't worked for me Either

Comment: @UmarKhan - what do you mean by _didn't work_? Did you get a compile error/ exception/ empty collection?

Comment: Yes It returned me the compiling error Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'

Comment: What i undertanstand by your suggestion is somthing similer to this public string Get(string itemSystemname, string fieldnames) {
                        return itemValues[itemSystemname].Distinct().FirstOrDefault(f => f.Key == fieldnames).Value;
        } this gives me the value of one key but what if i have the multiple values for same key?

Comment: @UmarKhan - please edit your question with the edited code so I can properly see but why use Distinct? or FirstOrDefault (especially if you say you want a collection of values).

Comment: See me Updates. i have to use FirstOrDefault to get the default value where condition is met so i can get the value like this @Person.Get("GeneralSettings", "Name")

Comment: @UmarKhan -  So what is the problem with what you wrote?

Comment: the problem comes in where i have multiple collections of same fields, see my question now with the Output i am getting and how the output i want

Comment: I have solved the issue your suggestion for using Dictionary instead of KeyValuePair helped but had to make few other changes as well to make it work. Still i Wonder why i cant get the value like this item["Id"] i have to use TryGetValue. Does performance will be effected this way?

Comment: @UmarKhan - If you changed to `Dictionary` then performance will improve because searching a `key` in  `Dictionary` in o(1) whereas in a `List` it is o(n)

Comment: @UmarKhan - Also if you did go with the `Dictionary` like I wrote in my solution please consider marking question as solved :)